# Changing MenuStrip ForeColor when hovering

Tags: c#, winforms

How to change menuStrip ForeColor when hovering it? I've managed to make the background color transpared using this code:

```
private class MyRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
    {
        public MyRenderer() : base(new MyColors()) { }
    }

    private class MyColors : ProfessionalColorTable
    {
        public override Color MenuItemSelected
        {
            get { return Color.Transparent; }

        }
        public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin
        {
            get { return Color.Transparent; }
        }

        public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd
        {
            get { return Color.Transparent; }
        }

        public override Color MenuItemBorder
        {
            get { return Color.Transparent; }
        }
    }
```

Now I want just the ForeColor to change when I hover it. Please help

Comment: @EugenePodskal Its Not duplicate. That question change backcolor. its forecolor

Comment: @EugenePodskal no, just the ForeColor I want to change

Comment: Understood. But unfortunately I am unable to remove the flag.

Comment: Proper attribution is required at SO, a link to the original post and a link to the poster's profile.

Comment: i think i've found a way, i used the mouseenter and mouseleave events to change the forecolor

Comment: @Ian If you asked a question and found an answer on your own it is considered a good move to post your own solution and mark it as accepted. Such answer will help future visitors with similar problems   .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    //Assuming black is the forecolor

    private void ToolStripMenuItem1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolStripMenuItem1.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
    }

    private void ToolStripMenuItem1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolStripMenuItem1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this a very old question, but I was in need of this and the selected answer is...not adequate for modern times, therefore, I'll like to share my solution:

```
public class MyRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    public OSThemeColors Colors { get; set; } //<- Your Custom Colors Colection

    public MyRenderer(ProfessionalColorTable table) : base(table) { }

    protected override void OnRenderItemText(ToolStripItemTextRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        e.TextColor = Colors.TextActive; 
        base.OnRenderItemText(e);
    }
    protected override void OnRenderItemBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Item.BackColor = Colors.Surface;
        base.OnRenderItemBackground(e);
    }
    protected override void OnRenderMenuItemBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.Selected)
        {
            Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Colors.Accent);
            Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, e.Item.Size);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rc); 
        }
    }       
}
```

Then this:

```
toolBar.RenderMode = ToolStripRenderMode.Professional;
toolBar.Renderer = new MyRenderer(new CustomColorTable(OScolors)) { MyColors = OScolors };
```